# Manipulating the HDD password via an SATA-USB adapter

Tags: usb, ssd, sata, password-recovery, secure-erase

This question is related to
https://superuser.com/questions/946577/the-master-password-of-transcend-ssd.
I've forgotten the password of Transcend SSD370 ,which I set.
When I boot my PC by a live CD with the SSD connected to the SATA port,
The screnn asking the HDD(SSD) password appears. 
I cannot use the live CD.

As for Secure Erase, there is the following advice.
"Only execute a secure erase when running the SSD directly from a SATA port, since problems may arise otherwise."
https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SSD_Secure_Erase
I'm going to connect the SSD via an SATA-USB adapter
and try to erase the HDD(SSD) password by MHDD or WHDD.
Can there be any danger ?

Comment: If you have a password set it likely won't work.  At this point are you willing t brick the device?  You will need to clarify what "MHDD" and "WHDD" are exactly.

Comment: I want to use the SSD. I don't want to brick it.
"MHDD" is a freeware for low-level HDD diagnostics.
"WHDD" is the linux version of "MHDD",and it is included in SystemRescueCD. 
HDD Unlock Wizard, ATAPWD.EXE and HDAT2 are for such a purpose,too,